# Having "UnknownSessionException: There is no session with id" on Oauth Resource Server after Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm working on Resource Server with Spring 4.3.21.RELEASE and Spring Security 4.2.10.RELEASE,

I have configured my Resource Server like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class Oauth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER");
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
        config.resourceId("resource_server");
        RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
        remoteTokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("http://my_url_to_validate_token/");
        remoteTokenServices.setClientId("cliend_id");
        remoteTokenServices.setClientSecret("secred_id");
        config.tokenServices(remoteTokenServices);
    }
}
```

Debugging *RemoteTokenServices.loadAuthentication* and *OAuth2AuthenticationManager.authenticate* are working properly and doing the correct validation and authentication.

but after that I'm getting this error

```
Jan 04, 2019 4:58:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [apiServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filtered request failed.] with root cause
org.apache.shiro.session.UnknownSessionException: There is no session with id [0bfdf9b2-7e2b-421c-97d3-e0fef7f5a531]
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.AbstractSessionDAO.readSession(AbstractSessionDAO.java:170)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager.retrieveSessionFromDataSource(DefaultSessionManager.java:236)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager.retrieveSession(DefaultSessionManager.java:222)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractValidatingSessionManager.doGetSession(AbstractValidatingSessionManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.lookupSession(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.lookupRequiredSession(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:112)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.setAttribute(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:216)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DelegatingSession.setAttribute(DelegatingSession.java:151)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.ProxiedSession.setAttribute(ProxiedSession.java:128)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpSession.setAttribute(ShiroHttpSession.java:202)
```

Is there something extra that is required to configure ?

Looking forward to your help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issues it seems related with the spring security mechanism to protect against session fixation attacks and the ShiroFilter which probably is creating a new session, which spring considers as session fixation attack.

One solution is disable the session fixation of spring Security, (not a good option)

```
http.sessionManagement().sessionFixation().none();
```

The other is change the order of the filters, previously I had defined in this order

```
//Shiro Filter
FilterRegistration.Dynamic shiroFilterRegistration = servletContext.addFilter("shiroFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy("shiroFilter"));
shiroFilterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/*");
//Shiro Filter

//Spring security filter
FilterRegistration.Dynamic filterRegistration = servletContext.addFilter(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME, DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
filterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/protected_resource");
// Spring security filter
```

If we change the order

```
//Spring security filter
FilterRegistration.Dynamic filterRegistration = servletContext.addFilter(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME, DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
filterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/protected_resource");
// Spring security filter

//Shiro Filter
FilterRegistration.Dynamic shiroFilterRegistration = servletContext.addFilter("shiroFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy("shiroFilter"));
shiroFilterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/*");
//Shiro Filter
```

We get rid of this exception